# ESXi 6.0 mounting RDM as local volume

Tags: esxi

I've just updated my ESXi host to 6.0 and I've noticed a weird side effect. Now when booting my RDM local device is automounted by the Hypervisor itself and my VM using it can't boot because the device is locked by the OS (the error I'm getting is `Failed to lock the file`).

If I list all devices:

```
[root@esx:~] esxcli storage filesystem list
Mount Point                                        Volume Name  UUID                                 Mounted  Type             Size          Free
-------------------------------------------------  -----------  -----------------------------------  -------  ------  -------------  ------------
/vmfs/volumes/4cdacf34-9bc2bc46-e644-d48564c85da5  SYSTEM HDU   4cdacf34-9bc2bc46-e644-d48564c85da5     true  VMFS-5   154618822656  127827705856
/vmfs/volumes/4cdacf03-d1fb2b7d-6384-d48564c85da5  DATA HDU     4cdacf03-d1fb2b7d-6384-d48564c85da5     true  VMFS-5  2000112582656  893103636480
/vmfs/volumes/5000b526-be6827b9-b9e9-009c02a7fbf2               5000b526-be6827b9-b9e9-009c02a7fbf2     true  vfat        299712512      83451904
/vmfs/volumes/ad7377ea-9bfcba10-6bad-896a6ee35f64               ad7377ea-9bfcba10-6bad-896a6ee35f64     true  vfat        261853184      87711744
/vmfs/volumes/0baa70e5-8a38dacf-3d88-bca98a363fc0               0baa70e5-8a38dacf-3d88-bca98a363fc0     true  vfat        261853184     122646528
/vmfs/volumes/3c3693e8-f77a642a-1910-5c6bdcb26d3a  Hypervisor3  3c3693e8-f77a642a-1910-5c6bdcb26d3a     true  vfat        299778048     157663232
/vmfs/volumes/b901cb7d-fd6e00e0-e5eb-b36b42d0950f  Hypervisor2  b901cb7d-fd6e00e0-e5eb-b36b42d0950f     true  vfat        261853184     261849088
/vmfs/volumes/4cdacf0f-59b94c5a-79e7-d48564c85da5               4cdacf0f-59b94c5a-79e7-d48564c85da5     true  vfat       4293591040    4269015040
/vmfs/volumes/5b569e71-4ede41ca-d19f-f2af4b6cee7c  Hypervisor1  5b569e71-4ede41ca-d19f-f2af4b6cee7c     true  vfat        261853184     169762816
/vmfs/volumes/localRDM                             RDM          5512f47e-00000000-0000-000000000000     true  ufs     1998251364352  288346738688
```

The device I'm trying to unmount is the last one

```
Mount Point                                        Volume Name  UUID                                 Mounted  Type             Size          Free
-------------------------------------------------  -----------  -----------------------------------  -------  ------  -------------  ------------
/vmfs/volumes/localRDM                             RDM          5512f47e-00000000-0000-000000000000     true  ufs     1998251364352  288346738688
```

[As stated by docs](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2004605) I've tried to unmount it but the OS is complaining and doesn't seem to want to unmount it:

```
[root@esx:~] esxcli storage filesystem unmount -l RDM
No volume with label 'RDM' was found
[root@esx:~] esxcli storage filesystem unmount -p /vmfs/volumes/localRDM
No NAS volume was found mounted on '/vmfs/volumes/localRDM'
[root@esx:~] esxcli storage filesystem unmount -u 5512f47e-00000000-0000-000000000000
No volume with uuid '5512f47e-00000000-0000-000000000000' was found
```

According to the docs, the syntax to unmount a device is:

```
# esxcli storage filesystem unmount [-u UUID | -l label | -p path ]
```

but as you can see no results so far.

I was wondering if I remove the vmdk file for this device and recreate it may solve the problem, but I'm afraid I will loose all data in it.

**Editted 1**

Ok, I've deleted the vmdk file mapping but ESXi is still automounting the disk (and no, there is no loss of data)

**Editted 2**

I see that there is no direct relation with my disk being passed through and ESXi automounting it as I've plugged a newly formatted UFS2 drive and ESXi is automounting it too (and there is no RDM for this one created yet)

Comment: Have you tried recreating the RDM mapping since you updated? This usually makes the disk unavailble locally.

Comment: Yes I've did it, no results so far (I've tried to replace the disk also but same bahaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue with RDM UFS drives used in NAS4Free being mapped as a folder, so I went to the VMWare Forums and asked for help.

Here's the answer from user themiron on the VMWare Forums.

> it's possible to blacklist ufs module with following esxcli command,
> so no automount of ufs volumes will happen. host reboot is required
>
> $ esxcli system module set -m ufs -e false

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/517516
(added the link to the original source as pointed out)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Thanks for bringing the essential part of your quoted source here.  Please also add a link to your source for proper attribution.  Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Thanks man! Come to think of it the solution is quite obvious :-) Now I've downgraded to 5.5 but I have a copy of my 6.0 installation, so I'll try it!